# Use sudo while editing over SSH?

Tags: ssh, remote

I'm using the `C-x C-f` option to use SSH to edit a file.

The file I'm editing requires my SSH user to use `sudo`.

When I start editing the file it says read-only. How can I remotely edit files requiring `sudo`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what is the convention for dealing with questions already answered elsewhere in the stackexchange network ("cross-site duplicates"), but [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs) has a detailed (and looking at the current manual, still up-to-date) answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [TRAMP multi-hops](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html). For instance, if you want to edit the remote file `/root/salary.txt`

```
/ssh:homer@powerplant|sudo:powerplant:/root/salary.txt
```

The example is taken from the [Mastering Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org) book.

Comment: You can omit the second `powerplant` if you stay on the machine you're sshing to. Source: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc18 . Edit: I was wrong. I didn't read the page thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a command for automating @Manuel Uberti's answer. The second one is the one I'd use. It uses the first one for remote files and uses [crux](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux) for local files.

```elisp
(require 'crux)
(require 's)

(defun my--reopen-remote-file-as-root ()
  "Reopen a remote file as root over tramp."
  (find-alternate-file (let* ((parts (s-split ":" buffer-file-name))
            (hostname (nth 1 parts))
            (filepath (car (last parts))))
           (concat "/ssh" ":" hostname "|" "sudo" ":" hostname ":" filepath))))


(defun my/reopen-file-as-root ()
  "Reopen a local or remote file as root."
  (interactive)
  (if (file-remote-p default-directory)
      (progn
    (my--reopen-remote-file-as-root)))
  (crux-reopen-as-root))
```

Comment: It doesn't check if current buffer is already opened with sudo(contains "sudo" in its name).